# How to update and delete specific comma separated values in text file? C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am a beginner and trying to make an inventory program for a school project but my c++ knowledge is very shallow. How can I update a specific data field / delete a specific data field given that the storing of data in my txt file is comma separated? This is the code I've got so far.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <vector>
    #include <sstream>
    using namespace std;

    string ItemID,
           description,
           name,
           category,
           manufacturer,
           SellingPrice,
           cost,
           StoreUnit,
           UnitSold,
           year,
           month,
           day;

    int choice=0;

    void mainmenu();
    void adddata();
    void savedata();
    void updatedata();
    float txtline(int);
    void searchdata();
    void showdata();

    vector<string> split(string strToSplit, char delimeter)
    {
        stringstream ss(strToSplit);
        string item;
        vector<std::string> splittedStrings;
        while (getline(ss, item, delimeter))
        {
           splittedStrings.push_back(item);
        }
        return splittedStrings;
    }

    vector <string> list;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------//

    int main()
    {
     mainmenu();

     while (choice==1)
     {
       adddata();
       mainmenu();
     }
     while (choice==2)
     {
       updatedata();
     }
     while (choice==2)
     {
       updatedata();
     }
     while (choice==5)
     {
      showdata();
      mainmenu();
     }
     while (choice==6)
     {
       return 0;
     }


    }

    void mainmenu()
    {
      cout << "___________________________________________________\n"
              "|                                                 |\n"
              "|       *** Inventory Management Program ***      |\n"
              "|              1 - Add New Record                 |\n"
              "|              2 - Update Data                    |\n"
              "|              3 - Delete Data field              |\n"
              "|              4 - Delete Record                  |\n"
              "|              5 - Show Record                    |\n"
              "|              6 - Exit                           |\n"
              "|_________________________________________________|\n"
              "        Please Select Your Next Choice: ";
      cin >> choice;
      cout << endl;
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    void adddata()
    {
      cout << "*** Inventory Management Program *** \n"
           << endl
           << "Please Enter A New Record:\n";
      cout << endl;

      cout << "Item ID: ";
      cin.ignore();
      getline(cin,ItemID);

      cout << "Item Name: ";
      getline(cin,name);

      cout << "Item Description: ";
      getline(cin,description);

      cout << "Category: ";
      getline(cin,category);

      cout << "Manufacturer: ";
      getline(cin,manufacturer);

      cout << "Selling Price: RM";
      getline(cin,SellingPrice);

      cout << "Cost Price: RM";
      getline(cin,cost);

      cout << "Units in Store: ";
      getline(cin,StoreUnit);

      cout << "Units Sold: ";
      getline(cin,UnitSold);

      cout << "Year of Date First Introduced: ";
      getline(cin,year);

      cout << "Month of Date First Introduced: ";
      getline(cin,month);

      cout << "Day of Date First Introduced: ";
      getline(cin,day);

      savedata();

      cout << endl;
      cout << "All your data have been successfully stored.";
      cout << endl;
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------

    void savedata()
    {
      ofstream file;
      file.open("Milestone2.txt", fstream::app);

      file << ItemID << " , " << name << " , " << description << " , "
           << category << " , " << manufacturer << " , " << SellingPrice <<
           " , " << cost << " , " << StoreUnit << " , " << UnitSold <<
           " , " << year << " , " << month << " , " << day <<"\n";

      file.close();
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void showdata()
    {
        string getcontent;
        ifstream openfile ("Milestone2.txt");
        if(openfile.is_open())
        {
            while(! openfile.eof())
            {
                getline(openfile, getcontent);
                cout << getcontent << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

Inside my Milestone2.txt file will be something like this after entering values.

```
1. 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2. MU0001, Mr.Rabbit, Plush Toy, Toy, Kids Wonderland, 10.00, 5.00, 100, 33, 2017, 4, 25
```

I've been finding solutions for hours but I can't figure it out how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing the data but what about the keys? As you are sequencially accepting the data from the user and storing it in the .txt file, you have only one option to go through data sequencially again to find out the value of a particular key and then only you can update it.

I will suggest you to store the key as well along with value and use '$' or some special character before the key name to differentiate key with the value. You will be able to search with the particular key and update its value.

I tried to answer as keeping in mind that you are a student. If you feel difficult to implement it then you can still iterate through comma (,) to find out a particular field and update/delete the same but next time when you iterate the same data then it will not match with your struct. I am not aware about the scope of your project fully, so thought just mention you this as well.